# Importing a UTF-8 XML file into SAS, how to set encoding?

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, import, sas

Firstly I am not a SAS programmer, so forgive me if this question is too easy or is difficult to follow!

I have an application which creates UTF-8 encoded XML files (and map files) that are to be read into SAS (9.3). These files can contain characters such the following (note the less than or equals):

```
<DocumentElement>
  <DATA>
    <TEXT>≤ 50 %</TEXT>
  </DATA>
</DocumentElement>
```

We have an external third party attempting to read these files, but I understand that SAS's default encoding is Wlatin1.

I have tried giving them a number of options based on the SAS docs as to what options to specify when reading these files, but I can't seem to get the correct combination of encoding options. Basically I want to import the XML, with a given MAP, into a dataset in SAS preserving the UTF-8 character encoding.

Assuming we are using libname xml, the [docs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/engxml/62845/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002484891.htm) suggest the following to read the xml:

```
filename NHL 'C:\My Documents\XML\NHL.xml';
filename MAP 'C:\My Documents\XML\NHL.map';
libname NHL xml xmlmap=MAP;

proc print data=NHL.TEAMS; 
run;
```

Which statements do I have to apply encoding options to, (I have tried the libname statement with XMLENCODING, INENCODING and OUTENCODING

- I have just noticed there is an ENCODING flag (instead of the above options) is that what I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, think I figured this out.

It turns out SAS has a session encoding, which it will try to transcode the data to if the input files do not match. Running SAS with a session encoding of UTF-8 avoids all of these issues, and you can then specify the ENCODING= option if required for any files (which I don't have to, as they are already utf-8).

SAS have a paper about this [here](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/92unicodesrvr.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Whichever encoding is used during your sas session, you can use `filename`'s `encoding=` option, which will inform sas about the encoding used by that external file. It will not impact the encoding used to write the data in a sas table, but will make sure the input files are read correctly.

```
filename NHL 'C:\My Documents\XML\NHL.xml' encoding="utf-8";
filename MAP 'C:\My Documents\XML\NHL.map' encoding="utf-8";
```

Note however that SAS expects utf-8 BOM characters to be present.